# How can I literally print out an escape sequence in python?

Tags: python, escaping

Is there a way to litterally print an escape sequence such as \n? For example:

```
print "Hello\nGoodbye"
```

The output of this would be:

```
Hello
Goodbye
```

Is there a way to get it to literally print out this?

```
Hello\nGoodbye
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the string in [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr):

```
>>> mystr = "Hello\nGoodbye"
>>> print mystr
Hello
Goodbye
>>> print repr(mystr)
'Hello\nGoodbye'
>>> # Remove apostrophes
>>> print repr(mystr)[1:-1]
Hello\nGoodbye
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use raw strings (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html)). Just add an `r` before the string:

```
>>> print r"hello\nworld"
hello\nworld
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpy write:

```
r'Hello\nGoodbye'
```

r is for raw string.